# Problem when requesting a form using prototype on internet explorer 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, prototype, request

I'm trying to make a request using prototype 1.6.1 on ie 8, the following code works on Firefox:

```
var myForm = document.forms[0];
myForm.request({


onSuccess: 
        function(transport) {
            var url = getPath() + nomeAcao+'?modulo='+modulo;
            window.location = url;
        }
});
```

When debugging, i get an error on the "myForm.request" line, it says i can't call this method on this object. Anyone knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
myForm.request(...);
```

try

```
Form.request(myForm, ...);
```